# Nested query/Navigation Property collection

Tags: breeze

Assume the following models: (example taken from Breeze DocCode)

```
public class Customer {

    public Guid CustomerID { get; internal set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDetail{
    public string name{ get; set; }
}

public class Order {

    public int OrderID {get; set;}
    public Guid? CustomerID {get; set;}

    public SomeDetail detail {get; set;}
}
```

Nested queries against single Navigation Properties are clear to me. How could this be done if the Navigation Property is a collection? Something like this:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Customers")
                 .where("Orders.detail.name", "==", someName);
```

As "Text":
Select all Customers where the name of the detail of any order this customer has equals someCondition?

I am running into errors here because

```
.where("Orders.detail.name, "=", someCondition)
```

is not possible due to the collection. 
Is there a short way to check for this conditions without building up a number off collections and filtering per hand?

Any help much appreciated here.

Comment: Yes ... you can't do that yet. I assume you mean "Give me every Customer that has an Order with a detail whose name is 'someName'". Such a query would require two "Any" clauses. Today's OData spec doesn't support that. We're working on it. I actually have a way to do this query if you only need to answer this question. It involves a custom query method on the controller. You can't write a client-side filter or expand. All you can do is pass parameters such as 'someName'. Let me know if you want that. Meanwhile, our backlog has a request to make this kind of thing easier/possible.

Comment: I would very much like too see this way. This would help me alot to simplify things.

Comment: It's not where I want it to be yet and I'm not ready to talk about it much but I pushed to github a DocCode test in queryTests.js called "orders for Chai". The corresponding `NorthwindController` method is `OrdersForProduct`. Use it for inspiration. We will do much better.

Answer (score 1):

As of Breeze 1.4.6, we have added support for two new query operators: "any" and "all"

This means that your query can now look something like this.

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Customers")
   .where("Orders", "any", "detail.name", "==", someName);
```

See: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples

Comment: In this case Query does not return only the Customers with Orders.Detail.name == somename, if condition satisfies on any one, it returns matching as well as other entries also right?

Comment: This query returns ALL customers that have ANY orders with 'detail.name' equaling {someName}.

Comment: Thanks Jay for Reply. I have another question. when I query as above what I find is, there are also records in the resultset with 'detail.name' other than "somename" also. Means Condition which satisfy as well as doesn't satisfy, and in latter case Orders obj is null. Cant we filter both Parent class as well as Child class as we do joins in sql query?