# Adding an "Or" clause on the server for breeze query

Tags: breeze, single-page-application, devforce

So we want to be able to search for a person by their phone number. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646217/nested-query-navigation-property-collection) SO post I gather that adding a where clause through a navigation property that is a list doesn't work in breeze yet.

That is ok with me because breeze provides an awesome way to do [server side properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704466/how-to-properly-send-action-parameter-along-with-query-in-breezejs/13793910#13793910). However when I write my query on the server I need the extra where clause to be added as an "OR" to the query so that is doesn't interfere with where clauses that I already have on the client. I am  doing this on the server but it isnt working. (Note this is using the DevForce Predicate Builder):

```
var pred = PredicateBuilder.False<Person>();
pred.Or(x => x.PhoneNumbers.Any(y => y.Value.StartsWith(searchString)));
var qry = _contextProvider.Context.People.Where(pred);
```

Am I building the predicate wrong or is what I am doing being added as and "And" clause and thus interfering with my other where clauses from the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated post: 11/25/13

As of Breeze 1.4.6, 'any' and 'all' operators are now supported.

So your client side Breeze query would look something like:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("People").where("PhoneNumbers", "any", "Value", "startsWith", searchString);
```

This assumes that you have a "People" endpoint that returns a person object that has a "PhoneNumbers" property that in turn has its own "Value" property.

Also see: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples

### Older post

Breeze does support or'ing predicates together as in:

```
 var pred = Predicate.create("ShipCity", "stArtsWiTH", "F")
                         .or("ShipCity", "startswith", "C");
 var q = EntityQuery.from("Orders").where(pred);
```

What breeze does not yet support are the 'any' and 'all' operators.  Although these will be supported in the near future.

Comment: Yes but if you add a where clause to your query on the server will it be added as an 'or' or an 'and'? We have a where clause on the client that searches by name and when we add a clause on the server we want it to be added as an 'or' so that the name search is still relevant. Thus when given the string "doe" it will check the patients last name 'OR' his phone number.

Comment: Any server clauses are effectively 'anded' with what is passed from the client.  This is deliberate so that the client cannot access information that is broader in scope than what the server defines as safe. But if you want you can execute two queries that accomplish the same thing (one against your base resource and one against your base resource with the name specified.) and then 'or' together the results.